# How do I install systemd from jessie backports?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, apt, debian-jessie

I'm trying to upgrade my systemd from version 215 (the current version for jessie) to the backports version (version 230).  I tried the straightforward approach of:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd/jessie-backports systemd-container/jessie-backports
```

However, this seems to have the negative side effect of uninstalling XFCE and a host of other bluetooth and networking things.  To fix this, I had to boot into recovery mode, downgrade systemd, and reinstall `task-xfce-desktop`.

I don't understand exactly why this dependency exists, and I'm not sure how to diagnose it.  Does someone know how to install systemd and not break XFCE on Jessie? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted.. can you give me some explanation as to why this is not a good question?  This gave me a good amount of grief for a day and the answer was not obvious, even after a whole bunch of Googling.

Answer (score 1):

`apt install -t jessie-backports systemd`

(or `apt-get` instead of `apt`, if you prefer.)

This will automatically take all dependencies from jessie-bpo, if necessary.

Note, that you might want to install `systemd-container`, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.  Instead of using `install`, I had to use `dist-upgrade`.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade systemd/jessie-backports systemd-container/jessie-backports udev/jessie-backports libpam-systemd/jessie-backports
```

It turns out that you have to explicitly include a couple of other dependencies (`udev` and `libpam-systemd`) in order to avoid swathes of other useful packages from being removed, like `network-manager`.